# android apk parse error

Tags: android, apk, parse-error, android-install-apk

I create an apk but I can't install this.
this way:Build > Generate Signed APK...

```
**Parse Error**
The was a aproblem while parsing the package.
```

I am using Note 5 and have Android 6 (API23)

I tried create a new project with same options and create apk and this apk is installed my device.

Where did I make mistakes?
And you need other codes for the help, just tell me.

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "***"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile project(':***')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.technicalnotes.org/fix-parse-error-in-android-there-is-a-problem-parsing-the-package/

Comment: I'm having the same exact issue... same API version (23)...